# Verify in_app_purchase payment data using .net core

Tags: c#, flutter, .net-core, google-pay

How to verify payment data on backend using .net core, where payment has been performed using google payment pay functionality in flutter.

I found a description on this site: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/***packageName***/purchases/products/***productId***/tokens/***token***

My question is what is token:
on given site there is a description: 
*token  string  The token provided to the user's device when the inapp product was purchased. The token provided to the user's device when the in-app product was purchased.*

But this request must be authorized and I follow steps described here:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization
and when I perfomed action https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=...&client_id=... on webbrowser as a test i was ask about access.

But I will perfome this action on backend!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCKAO.png)

Thank you,